# Laravel 5.2 Access a file from storage directory

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have placed my uploads in the storage folder. Now, I want to display these uploads into my view. I have tried doing this:

view:

```
<img src="{{route("image_download", ['id' => Auth::guard('admin')->user()->AccountOfficerID, 'filename' => Session::get('avatar')] )}}" class=img-circle alt="Avatar" />
```

route:

```
Route::get('images/{id}/{$filename}', ['as' => 'image_download', function ($id, $filename)
{
    $path = storage_path() . '/uploads/images/admins/' . $id . '/icon_size/' . $filename;

    if (File::exists($path)) {
        $type = File::mimeType($path);

        return response()->download($path);
    }
}]);
```

And other various methods I have searched. But none worked for me. I have checked the path and it is correct. However, it is not displaying any image at all. I hope someone could point me to the right track. Thank you.

**EDIT**
There seems to be a 404 error in the browser console relating to the file. But I can access the file with the path returned through the browser.

Comment: can you check in console or n/w tab what's status error is coming....it might be permission issue as you saying path is correct.

Comment: @Naincy would that be visible in the logs also? Cause if it would be, there are no errors.

Comment: are you able to access that path directly in browser ?

Comment: @Naincy yes I could. I tried printing the resulting path and yes I could access it with browser.

Comment: I think I think Storage::exists($path) would work as well. As you using Storage directory
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem

Comment: @Naincy I just checked my console and it returns 404 not found.

Comment: Yes, That's what I saying in my prv comments :)  so it means the path is not correct .....it not able to find the file at that path............will be good if u share code for uploading file....

Comment: Well I don't understand why. It seems to go to the public folder
http://localhost/IMS/public/images/5/146865481318579424818757769926457n.jpg

But I the path is not like that. My images are in the storage folder.

Comment: share echo $path ....!

Comment: @Naincy Here is the path C:\xampp\htdocs\IMS\storage/uploads/images/admins/5/icon_size/146865481318579424818757769926457n.jpg

Comment: doesn't seems error in code...

Comment: @Naincy I'm sorry for wasting your time. I just accidentally placed a $ sign in the route parameters. Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just an error in the parameters. I have accidentally placed a $ sign. Thank you for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all have you modified your config/filesystems.php?

Also you don't do as you dont need to call route() in src image.

```
`<img src="{{route("image_download", ['id' => Auth::guard('admin')->user()->AccountOfficerID, 'filename' => Session::get('avatar')] )}}" class=img-circle alt="Avatar" />`
```

Instead do asset() and put the route in your `<a>` if you want it linked

```
<img src="{{asset("image_source")}}" class=img-circle alt="Avatar" />
```

Have a look at this tutorial on how to use [Laravel Storage](http://anytch.com/laravel-storage-uploading-multiple-files/) correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
<img src="{{ url('image_download/'.$id.'/'.$filename) }}"/>
```